# Pausing entire program from a thread spawned from a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

My program currently looks something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def something():
    time.sleep(10)

def function1():
    if condition1:
        Thread(target=something).start()


def function2():
    if condition2:
        Thread(target=something).start()

def function3():
    if condition3:
        Thread(target=something).start()

def main():
    Thread(target=function1).start()
    Thread(target=function2).start()
    Thread(target=function3).start()

main()
```

If function 1 has already spawned a thread calling something() ,I dont want functions 2 and 3 to spawn another thread calling something().

Comment: You'll probably need a non-blocking Semaphore and set a status variable when you've executed the first time.

Comment: Never hear of that term. Looks like I'm gonna have to do some research. The thought of a status variable did cross my mind. I shall try and respond.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the code just creates three independent threads and each of these threads then can create another thread doing something, but again completely independent of each other (so getting 3 soemthing threads at max).
Now you ask that these threads interact in a certain manner: "something" should be executed just once. Hence thread "something" must be instantiated only one time and the call must be secured with a lock. Function threads must know about that "something" thread, so you need to create "something" thread in main() and pass it to the function threads.
All in all I am not sure that this will give a simple program structure and it might be good to revise what you want to achieve.

Comment: Looks like I will have to look into thread locks. The answer above this was also referencing this.

Answer (score 1):

Try following pseudo-code:

```
import threading
import time

lock = threading.Lock()


def something():
    time.sleep(10)


def function1():
    if condition1 and lock.acquire(timeout=5):
        threading.Thread(target=something).start()


def function2():
    if condition2 and lock.acquire(timeout=5):
        threading.Thread(target=something).start()


def function3():
    if condition3 and lock.acquire(timeout=5):
        threading.Thread(target=something).start()


def main():
    threading.Thread(target=function1).start()
    threading.Thread(target=function2).start()
    threading.Thread(target=function3).start()


main()
```

Comment: I will try this but however I must mention that it's a rare occurrence but when it happens it shits the entire program up.